# Why doesn't /proc exist in OS X?

Tags: filesystem, kernel, macos

What is the reason that `/proc` does not exist in OS X? I was curious to find file descriptors that a process was using in my Mac. The way I do it in linux is to go in `/proc/fd` folder of that process.

How do I find what `fd`s are used by a process?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Going back to basics : Ubuntu is a GNU/Linux, OS X is a FreeBSD : Different systems, different way to work.

On OS X you can use `lsof` to see the open files.

```
$lsof -p 68180
```

would show you every files opened by the process with pid 68180.

Comment: This post doesn't really answer the question. It states that the reson is FreeBSD, but FreeBSD does have [`/proc`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procfs&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE)

Comment: it does not answer the question.   E.g. /proc/cpuinfo or /proc/meminfo - these have nothing to do with lsof.

Comment: macOS isn't based off of FreeBSD, but rather a mixture of BSD and FreeBSD. [This chart may be of use.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Unix_history-simple.svg)

Comment: If you need `/proc` for machine processing, `lsof -F` produces machine readable output. See the man pages for its spec. (`man lsof` on your command line)