# OS X equivalent of linux /proc dir

Tags: unix

I am thinking about running dstat on Mac. But some of the locations of data are different from Linux: notice the **/proc/stat:**

```
Module dstat_cpu24 failed to load. (Cannot open file /proc/stat)
Module dstat_disk24_old failed to load. (Cannot open file /proc/stat)
Module dstat_net failed to load. (Cannot open file /proc/net/dev)
Module dstat_page24 failed to load. (Cannot open file /proc/stat)
Module dstat_sys failed to load. (Cannot open file /proc/stat)
```

Is there a reference detailing the mapping from the standard Linux to Mac?

Comment: There is no `/proc` or similar on OS X.

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't /proc exist in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119124/why-doesnt-proc-exist-in-os-x)

Comment: Yes I realized - but then how do folks map the linux dirs to mac?