# macOS alternative for /proc/net/dev

Tags: macos, unix

Can we have an exact alternative (for macOS) to the output for `/proc/net/dev` on Linux systems?

There's a slightly similar question at [OS X equivalent of linux /proc dir](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188426/os-x-equivalent-of-linux-proc-dir/) but I'm looking specifically for `/proc/net/dev`.

I am trying to run `speedometer` which is a `python script` that displays network usage history graphically. For example, in Ubuntu, I can run it in three terminals and it shows the `per second`, `per minute`, and `per hour` average `network speed` for a `given interface`. Maybe I can try another tool for the job?

speedometer is failing when it requests for the output of `/proc/net/dev`

Comment: This will get yes / no answers. If you want more than that, consider explaining what exactly you are trying to do other than ask if X is ported to Y.

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/119124/9058 for a way you could rephrase the question